# dateutil.tz package apparently missing when using Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

My python 2.7 code is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame

DF_rando = DataFrame([1,2,3])
```

...and then when I execute, I get a strange error regarding `dateutil.tz`.

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7 /Users/mattobrien/pandas_test.py
No module named dateutil.tz
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mattobrien/pandas_test.py", line 2, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from . import hashtable, tslib, lib
  File "pandas/tslib.pyx", line 37, in init pandas.tslib (pandas/tslib.c:76999)
ImportError: No module named dateutil.tz

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Very strange. I checked an indeed `dateutil.tz` is indeed installed. I uninstalled `Pandas` and reinstalled it to be sure. No issues there.

Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Needed these 2 lines.

`sudo pip install python-dateutil --upgrade`

`sudo pip install pytz --upgrade`

Comment: But did you discover why you were getting the error, given that you already had dateutil.tz installed?

Comment: I have tried everything including the above 2 lines and nothing works.  It says eveything is installed but wehn I try ti run a script that uses pandas I get the same error about dateutil not being found.

Comment: What ended up working for me was to download the python-dateutil-1.5.tar.gz 

Then untar the file and type in command line:
python setup.py install

Comment: why are you using sudo before installing..?